# How to filter rows by group in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose now I have some group data like

| GroupID | ID | Rank | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| B | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| C | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| C | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| D | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| D | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| D | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| D | 4 | 2 | 0 |

For each group,

1. I want to filter the group which has no rows which target=1.
2. Then I want to keep the row which target==1 and the rows which rank is higher than it. Some group may have many rows which target==1, and we choose the one which rank is lower as our target. For example for group C, the ID=1 and ID=3 all have target==1, we will keep the rows which the rank<=3. So we will get

| GroupID | ID | Rank | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| C | 4 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Can you check again description? Because seems not clear - e.g. `which the rank<=3` - why is returned last row with `rank=2` ? Whats happens if `target=0` ?

Comment: For each group, I think I need to find the one whose target==1 and has the lowest rank. Take group C for example, the rank is 3.  Then I need to filter the rows which rank > 3 in the group C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Rank` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) if target is not `1` and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for maximal `Rank` per group, so possible compare `Rank` column in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for less or equal:

```
s = df['Rank'].where(df['target'].eq(1)).groupby(df['GroupID']).transform('max')
df = df[df['Rank'].le(s)]
print (df)
   GroupID  ID  Rank  target
0        A   1     1       0
2        A   3     2       1
3        B   1     1       0
5        B   3     3       1
6        B   4     2       0
7        C   1     1       1
9        C   3     3       1
10       C   4     2       0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['Rank'].where(df['target'].eq(1)))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     2.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     3.0
6     NaN
7     1.0
8     NaN
9     3.0
10    NaN
Name: Rank, dtype: float64

print (s)
0     2.0
1     2.0
2     2.0
3     3.0
4     3.0
5     3.0
6     3.0
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
Name: Rank, dtype: float64
```

Comment: One more question. I found that there is no Target = 1 in some groups, I want to filter  these groups (all rows) at first. Then try to apply your method

Comment: @WenhaoZheng - answer was edited.

Comment: @WenhaoZheng - do you think filter for remove group `D` or for add group `D` (with target=0 only) ?

Comment: @WenhaoZheng ideally, better update the question to provide an example

Comment: @jezrael Yes if the group D has no rows which target==1, then the whole group will be removed. I think I can do this first? I have updated the question

Comment: @WenhaoZheng - hmmm, I think not necessary, because it alredy working for first solution. What is reason for do it?

Comment: this is indeed not needed, both solution already filter out the whole group when there is no target 1

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, make a first pass to slice the rows with target == 1 (using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)), then get the max rank per group using [`GroupBy.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) and select the rows with this maximum rank per group with classical [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) using [`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
thresh = df[df['target'].eq(1)].groupby('GroupID')['Rank'].max()

out = df[df['Rank'].le(df['GroupID'].map(thresh))]
```

output:

```
   GroupID  ID  Rank  target
0        A   1     1       0
2        A   3     2       1
3        B   1     1       0
5        B   3     3       1
6        B   4     2       0
7        C   1     1       1
9        C   3     3       1
10       C   4     2       0
```

thresholds:

```
>>> thresh
GroupID
A    2
B    3
C    3
```